# HIVE insert overwrite directory with json format

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can I insert overwrite directory with json schema?

There is raw hive avro table;
(this is actually has many fields)

```
tb_test--------
name string
kickname string
-----------------
```

then I want to save query result into some directory in hdfs by jsonserde.

I tried this.

```
insert overwrite directory '/json/'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "stat_name"="$._col0",
 "stat_interval"="$._col1"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
select name, nickname
from tb_test limit 100
```

But written json in /json/ has _colXX field name instead of the origin field name.

```
{"_col0":"basic_qv"," _col1":"h"}
{"_col0":"basic_qv","_col1 ":"h"}
{"_col0":"basic_qv","_col1 ":"h"}
{"_col0":"basic_qv"," _col1":"h"}
{"_col0":"basic_qv","_col1 ":"h"}
```

I expected

```
{"name":"basic_qv","nickname":"h"}
{"name":"basic_qv","nickname":"h"}
{"name":"basic_qv","nickname":"h"}
{"name":"basic_qv","nickname":"h"}
{"name":"basic_qv","nickname":"h"}
```

What will help this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue with AVRO format. Have you found the solution? Please let me know if you know any workarounds.

Comment: is avro output fotmar or table format? I couldnt find any workaround on hive. Instead I did this by spark. Run spark sql then export dataframe as json. spark support various export format in a nature.

Comment: AVRO is the required output file format. Yes, Spark is a good workaround.

Comment: @JihunNo could you share a sample avro file that you are trying out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your issue with a workaround (using JsonUDF with named_struct) is described here: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/issues/151

```
extract.hql:
add jar /home/myuser/lib/json-udf-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
create temporary function tjson as 'org.openx.data.udf.JsonUDF';

insert overwrite local directory '/json/'
select
tjson(named_struct("name", t.name,"nickname", t.nickname))
from tb_test t
;
```

Also you can create JsonSerDe-based table with columns defined, `insert overwrite` it and use table location instead of directory.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today. In case you don't want/can't use UDFs,
using this guideline: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html,
this worked for me (order of column should be different also using the `mapping` prefix:

```
insert overwrite directory '/json/'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "case.insensitive" = "false",
 "mapping._col0" = "stat_name",
 "mapping._col1" = "stat_interval"
)
select name, nickname
from tb_test limit 100
```